# How to properly cut an svg shape in two parts?

Tags: html, css, svg, adobe-illustrator

I have an svg logo, and the idea is - when you click on each half of it, you should be redirected to two different pages. So I've cut this logo in two equal pieces using illustrator to later match them together.

```
<div id="lobby">
    <div id="jekyll">
        <a href="#" >
        <img src="lobby/jekyll.svg" alt="dr.Jekyll">
        </a>
    </div>      
    <div id="hyde">
        <a href="#" >
        <img src="lobby/hyde.svg" alt="mr.Hyde">
        </a>
    </div>
</div>

CSS
#jekyll{
    float:left;
    width:50%;

}

#hyde{
    float:right;
    width:50%;

}
```

But the problem is - that, although two images match perfectly at the top, they start to mismatch closer to the bottom, i've tried the same technique with a less complicated image, and the same thing occurs there. Is there a proper way to do this, or an alternative?
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YXdymZ

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Keep the SVG intact, disable pointer-events: none in css so you can't click it. Position 2 rects almost invisible (eg opacity 0.0001) and attach click handlers or a hrefs to them.

Comment: Or keep the SVG as a single piece and wrap the separate `g` elements in their own links.

Comment: Thanks guys, I've actually had a similar idea in mind. Any idea as to why the images behave that way though?

Comment: Without an actual demo we can't tell...

Comment: Added a codepen link. As you can see - the top of the images align perfectly, but then it starts to mismatch. After a numerous reedits I've tried the same thing with a simple shape, and had the same effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The svg files are rendered at different heights (delta on my platform: 3px) in their `img` containers, in spite of the identical svg viewport dimensions.

While I cannot tell you the reason for this behavior, setting the `img` heights to identical values resolves the issue:

```
#jekyll img, #hyde img { height: 421px; }
```

**Update**

Absolute measures are unsatisfactory. There is another solution involving complementary CSS only ( online demo [here on codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RPERQG) ):

```
#jekyll{
    float:left;
    width:50%;
    margin-left: 1px; /* added */
}

#hyde{
    float:right;
    width:calc(50% - 1px); /* added */
}
#hyde img, #jekyll img { margin-left: -1px; } /* added */
```

Comment: The idea is for this image to occupy most of the screen and be adaptive, that's the reason for using svg in the first place. Setting images to fixed height doesn't really help with that. I might be wrong though, as you could've already guessed - I am pretty inexperienced.

Comment: have you tried to use a single `div` putting the `img` containers next to each other?

Comment: Have a look at [this variation](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KpbMXR): shrinking the _width_ of the hyde `div` by 1 px actually fixes the alignment, though the separating vertical line stillneeds to be fixed.

Comment: Got it - [see for yourself](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RPERQG). A negative left-margin on the `img` elements` does the trick. Still no explanation though. I have adjusted the answer accordingly.

Comment: Yeah, the last one works, thanks a lot. Although if you zoom out more than 50% it starts to mismatch again, but that's the best result I've had so far, so I'll stick with it.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why they weren't aligning perfectly was because the two SVG viewBoxes don't have the same dimensions.

Since you were only supplying widths for the two parent divs, the final heights for each image were being calculated by using the `viewBox` aspect ratios.

In your codepen, the `50%` widths being given to the two images (half of `#lobby`) resulted in a real width of 148.188px.  To simplify the calculations, let's round that to 148px.

To calculate the height for each image, the browser is using that width and scaling it based on the aspect ratio.

For jekyll the viewBox width and height are 61.08 x 163.904.

For hyde it is: 60.699 x 163.904

So the calculated heights for each will be:

```
Jekyll: 148 * 163.904/61.08  = 397px
  Hide: 148 * 163.904/60.699 = 400px
```

Hence the discrepancy.

Since the RHS (Hyde) is the narrower one, and it is left-aligned in the viewbox, a simple fix would be to modify the width value of the hyde viewBox to match Jekyll's.  That is, change the viewBox to:

```
viewBox="481.73 57.015 61.08 163.904"
```

I haven't tested, but I think that should work.